# Add a form control whilst building an array

Tags: angular

I'm building a form like so:

```
actions = [
        { id: 'walkTo', name: 'Walk To' },
        { id: 'use', name: 'Use' },
        { id: 'give', name: 'Give' },
        { id: 'pickUp', name: 'Pick Up' }
    ];

this.myForm = this.fBuilder.group({
            name: [null, [Validators.required]],
            age: [null, [Validators.required]],
            actions: this.buildActions(this.actions)
        });
```

But how can I add a control without a key to the formarray that's being built by the `buildActions` method. The reason I'm doing it this way, is that the array will be a list of checkboxes

```
buildActions(arr)
    {
        var resultArr = [];
        arr.forEach((x, index) => {
            resultArr.push(this.fBuilder.group({
                this.fBuilder.addControl(false)
            }))
        });
        return this.fBuilder.array(resultArr);
    }
```

It errors at the `this.fBuilder.addControl(false)` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's erroring because `FormBuilder.addControl()` isn't a function.

To build a simple form array, pass in an array of form controls like this:

```js
buildActions(arr): FormArray {
  const controls = arr.map(x => this.fBuilder.control(x));
  return this.fBuilder.array(controls);
}
```

It's also possible to nest form groups in a form array if you want to build a more complex form:

```js
buildActions(arr): FormArray {
  const groups = arr.map(x => this.fBuilder.group({
    text: this.fBuilder.control(x.text),
    checked: this.fBuilder.control(x.checked)
  }));
  return this.fBuilder.array(groups);
}
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tpcpzc